# HttpError 400 relating to a json response size being too large when running the python script from the Google Cloud ML BERT tutorial

Tags: python, nlp, httprequest, google-api-client, google-cloud-ml

I am new to Google Cloud and am learning BERT by following this great tutorial: “Incorporating natural language processing using AI Platform and BERT”. I get stuck when running embed.py as described in this section:
https://cloud.google.com/solutions/incorporating-natural-language-processing-using-ai-platform-and-bert?authuser=1#embedding_tokenized_text_using_bert (5.)

This is the relevant snipit from the embed.py output:

googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 400 when requesting https://us-central1-ml.googleapis.com/v1/projects/this-project-id/models/BERT/versions/bert_en_cased_L12_H768_A12:predict?alt=json returned "Response size too large. Received at least 3116404 bytes; max is 2000000."

And this is from the log:

jsonPayload: {
@type: "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.ml.v1.PredictionLogEntry"
numInstances: "1"
message: "Response size too large. Received at least 3441268 bytes; max is 2000000."
}
httpRequest: {
requestMethod: "POST"
requestUrl: “us-central1-ml.googleapis.com/v1/projects/this-project-id/models/BERT/versions/bert_en_cased_L12_H768_A12:predict?alt=json"
requestSize: "1299"
status: 400
responseSize: "75"
userAgent: "(gzip),gzip(gfe)"
remoteIp: "34.22.66.111"
}

Hope this is understandable. Any pointers to a fix or workaround would be greatly appreciated.